# PDF File Uploader with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I am trying to upload a PDF file using php MIME types. The code is producing the following error when I click upload :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/stylecraft/domains/stylecraft-yarns.co.uk/public_html/dev/_cms/upload_pdf2.php on line 44

Code:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "pdf");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$ok = false;
switch ($mime) {
   case 'image/jpeg':
   case 'application/pdf':
        $ok = true;
   default:
       die("Unknown/not permitted file type");
}

  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("../pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists: ";
      echo "<p>Image URL: <strong>" . $preferences->PREF_SHOPURL . "/pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "</strong></p>";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
      echo "<p>PDF URL: <strong>" . $preferences->PREF_SHOPURL . "/pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "</strong></p>";
      }
    }

else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have a corresponding **if** statement in your code:
**else** statements should have a corresponding "partner" which is the if.

you have:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

and you have another else below:

```
else {
}
```

In your code, the last `else` have no `if` before that's why you get the error

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but how can I make it all one big if, is that possible?

Comment: yes, there is a way, but I think you must edit your question first so that the answer you seek must be related. :)

Comment: the last else can be partnered with an if statement during checking of the file like: <br/> `if($finfo) {} ... else {}`